# How to multiply integer by an IEEE double without conversion instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm looking for a general idea. I know how IEEE float or double is stored, but I don't know how to exactly multiply it.

One idea I have is to store the integer as a double (in float registers) and then use normal double multiply instruction.

Is there any characteristic property when multplying IEEE double by an integer? As in "you have to only multiply the exponent" or something similar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html might be of use to you depending on what you are trying to do, you may not need the IEEE format for your application, keep track of the exponent yourself and use the whole thing as mantissa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply a single or double precision float by 2^n just by adding n to the exponent, but for any other multiplier value you'll be changing the mantissa too, and that is obviously going to be non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way to store the integer manually (without using any conversion instructions) as double?

Comment: If you know the value of the integer at compile time then yes, you can store it in any format you like, but if you're talking about run-time then no, there is no magic that will let you convert an integer to double for free without using either an explicit instruction for this or a whole bunch of integer bit twiddling instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I'll have to do some bit twiddling then ;)

Comment: Bit twiddling will always be slower than a conversion to double and FPU multiply for a general integer. There are only a few special case integers, like 2^n where twiddling will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you were on x86, you could use the `FIMUL` instruction, which does exactly what you want. But as you are on mips, you have no better way than converting and multiplying for the general case.